# Looping problems - finding a certain letter in a word

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops

I am trying to write a program in which the computer picks a word from a pre-defined list, and the user then inputs letters one by one to try and guess the word.

I am trying to loop the program so the user can keep guessing as many times as are number of letters in the word, regardless of whether they guess correctly or not.

However, for some reason the program currently only loops twice if they guess correctly, and not at all if they guess wrong. What am I doing wrong?

```
user_input = str(input("Please pick a letter you think is in the word I have chosen."))
for i in (0, len(computer_choice)) #computer_choice is the word the computer has generated
    if user_input in WordList:
        user_input = str(input("You got one of the letters! Keep going!"))
    else:
        user_input = str(input("You did not get one of the letters. Please try again. You have " + str(i) + " attempts left."))
```

Comment: What is `computer_choice`?

Comment: What is `computer_choice`? And you didn't indent the code in the for loop

Comment: And your code only guesses one letter. If you want to guess multiple letters, that needs to be repeated in a loop

Comment: yes, that is what I am trying to do, but how?

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is to ask for random letter guess from the user within a for loop that runs from 0 till the length of the word stored in the variable 'computer choice', something like this :

```
for i in range(0, len(computer_choice)) #computer_choice is the word the computer has generated
    user_input = str(input("Please pick a letter you think is in the word I have chosen."))

    if user_input in computer_choice:
        print "You got one of the letters! Keep going!"
    else:
        print "You did not get one of the letters. Please try again. You have " + str(len(computer_choice)-i-1) + " attempts left."
```

Comment: Also note the change made in the last line where I've written "...You have " + str(len(computer_choice)-i-1) + " attempts left.". The remaining number of choices are len(computer_choice) - i - 1.

Answer (score 0):

```
import random

ChosenWord = random.choice(["WordOne", "WordTwo"])

while True:
    user_input = str(input("Enter letter: "))

    if user_input.lower() in ChosenWord.lower():
        print("Correct!")
    else:
        print ("You Lost!")
        break
```

Not 100% sure what you are after but this piece of code loops the game until the user enters a incorrect letter

Comment: I added the **.lower**  so it isn't case sensitive, also since you are entering a string the game will break if you enter anything other than a string (try and except would fix this)